# Tensorflow summary: how to get items before evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to get a list of summaries created with a model in `tensorflow`. I know that [one can get a dictionary of key:value of evaluated summaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568675/parsing-summary-str-byte-string-evaluated-on-tensorflow-summary-object/34569074#34569074).

Can one get a list of summary keys before evaluating them from `summary_proto` object? I need it to initialize a dictionary of lists where I will store summaries from each epoch, instead of storing list of dictionaries.

```
summary_proto = tf.Summary()
```

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be easiest to initialize your dictionary of lists on demand, using the following code:

```
train_op = ...
summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()

summaries = {}

sess = tf.Session()

for _ in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
  _, summary_str = sess.run([train_op, summary_op], feed_dict=feed_dict)
  summary_proto = tf.Summary()
  summary_proto.ParseFromString(summary_str)

  for val in summary_proto.value:
    try:
      list_for_tag = summaries[val.tag]
    except KeyError:
      list_for_tag = []
      summaries[val.tag] = list_for_tag

    # Assuming all summaries are scalars.
    list_for_tag.append(val.simple_value)
```

---

However, to answer your original question, it is possible to get the individual tags by evaluating the `tag` **inputs** to the individual summary ops (which most likely do not depend on the result of training):

```
summaries = {}

sess = tf.Session()

all_summary_tensors = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SUMMARIES)

for summary_t in all_summary_tensors:
  tag_input = summary_t.op.inputs[0]  # The tag input is the 0th input.
  tags = sess.run(tag_input)

  if isinstance(tags, str):
    summaries[tags] = []
  else:
    for tag in tags.flatten():
      summaries[tag] = []
```